# Detecting end off a call PJSIP

Tags: c, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I am writing an application on Ubuntu 16.04 with PJSUA/PJSIP.
I need to detect when a call is hanged-up. Is there a sort off `call_state()` function ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_samples_pjsua.htm) and [here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSIP__INV.htm#ga083ffd9c75c406c41f113479cc1ebc1c) :
You have to modify the `static void on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e)` function like so :

```
/* Callback called by the library when call's state has changed */
static void on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(e);

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
    PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Call %d state=%.*s", call_id,
             (int)ci.state_text.slen,
             ci.state_text.ptr));


    if (ci.state == PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED) { 

        /*YOUR CODE HERE*/

    }
}
```

Comment: if you call out, other end stop session, this hook not firing, it is just runing if you hang off.